# Numbers, signs and units in text

Tags: math-mode, text, units

In the results section of my text I have to write sentences that more or less go like this:

"(...) the values are in a range of -5 - -2 kcal/mol (...)"

I wanted to:

1. Make some visual difference between hyphen and a minus sign, so it won't look bad in the text.
2. Prevent Latex from making a line break between the numbers or units.

My solution to this was to wrap each number in $...$, and to wrap the whole expression in \mbox{...} like this:

```
"(...) the values are in a range of \mbox{$-5$ - $-2$ kcal/mol} (...)"
```

It more or less works, but I am not sure if this is the correct and proper way to handle such thing. Are there any packages dedicated to solving this?

Comment: The canonical solution nowadays is `\usepackage{siunitx}` (then define `\DeclareSIUnit\calorie{cal}`, in your case) then write `\SI{-5}{\kilo\calorie\per\mole}` or `\SIrange{-5}{-2}{\kilo\calorie\per\mole}`.

Comment: Thank you, that solves the matter!